# Check if there is a value in db with if

Tags: php

I have to check if a value is present in two tables, through a left join, if there is a relationship write yes, otherwise no

every time I associate an evidence (tev_Evidenze) to the structure (tev_Tipi_accreditamento) the query should tell me for that structure there is evidence, only now at structure n6. no evidence is present and anyway I answer yes
code:

```
    <?php 
    $CONTROLLA = mysqli_query($riskmanagement,
                    "SELECT * FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze
ON tev_Tipi_accreditamento. ID_tipo_acc = tev_Evidenze.id_tipo_accreditamento
WHERE tev_Tipi_accreditamento.id_struttura = tev_Evidenze.id_struttura GROUP BY tev_Evidenze.id_struttura");

    $EVIDENZE=mysqli_num_rows($CONTROLLA);
    if($EVIDENZE==0)  {
        echo "SI";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
    ?>
```

The cycle is correct I am sure that in the db, there are no values ​​present in both tables but my if does not seem to work

NOTE:

```
<?php
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze
ON tev_Tipi_accreditamento. ID_tipo_acc = tev_Evidenze.id_tipo_accreditamento
WHERE tev_Tipi_accreditamento.id_struttura = tev_Evidenze.id_struttura GROUP BY tev_Evidenze.id_struttura";
$query = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, $query_string);
?>


<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>
<?php echo $row['id_struttura'] ;
    if($query_string==0)  {
        echo "SI";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The way your query is written it will always return 1 row. Try running the query in your SQL IDE to see that.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` will always return a row if there's a match in the left table. If you want to know if the relationship exists, use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You also have your test backwards. You should print `no` when the number of rows is `0`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the query is perfect and working

Comment: @Barmar the query is perfect and working

Comment: Perfect and returning one row.

Comment: Look at the values that it's returning. If there's no value in the second table, it will still return a row, but all the columns from the second table will be `NULL`.

Comment: Is there only 1 row in the `tev_Tipi_accreditamento` table? Since you don't filter anything, this should return all the rows in that table, along with all the related rows in the `tev_Evidenze` table.

Comment: Read http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @Barmar i edit mu question

Comment: @JayBlanchard  i edit mu question

Comment: You're still not filtering anything. The `WHERE` clause is another relationship between the two tables. However, putting something from the second table in the `WHERE` clause makes it act like `INNER JOIN` because the condition will never be true for `NULL` values.

Comment: @Barmar so how could i do?

Answer (score 0):

You're counting ALL the matches, not the number of matches for each structure. You can use the following:

```
SELECT s.id_struttura, IF(COUNT(e.id_struttura) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') AS matches
FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento AS s
LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze AS e ON s.id_struttura = e.id_struttura AND s.ID_tipo_acc = e.id_tipo_accreditamento
GROUP BY s.id_struttura
```

This will return a table like:

```
1 Yes
2 No
3 No
4 Yes
```

for each structure ID.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmSpMhoiVsuzPGr8s3APWr/0)

You can show the result with:

```
$CONTROLLA = mysqli_query($riskmanagement, "
    SELECT s.id_struttura, IF(COUNT(e.id_struttura) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') AS matches
    FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento AS s
    LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze AS e ON s.id_struttura = e.id_struttura AND s.ID_tipo_acc = e.id_tipo_accreditamento
    GROUP BY s.id_struttura") or die(mysqli_error($riskmanagement));
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($CONTROLLA)) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row['id_struttura']}</td><td>{$row['matches']}</td>
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: how to echo with this query what i want?

Comment: You echo it just like showing the results of any other query. I added it to the answer.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null

Comment: i add a comment in your asnwer

Comment: I rejected your edit. Edits should not be used for comments.

Comment: beyond use it was just to make you understand better, not to offend you

Comment: I understand, but those are the rules. If there's more to the problem, add it to your question, not my answer.

Comment: hahahaha okay okay, as you are touchy though :), I understood the rules, but really it was not my intention to offend you, I added to my question, can you give me a hand? to make an echo come out in the event of a false left join?

Comment: I wasn't offended, just trying to keep my answer and your comments separate.

Comment: `$query_string` is the `"SELECT ..."` string. `if ($query_string == 0)` doesn't make sense, why are you comparing a string to 0?

Comment: to check that there are no results in the db

Comment: But `$query_string` doesn't contain results, it's just the SQL string.

Comment: Can you show some sample table contents and the result you expect for each? It's hard to tell exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: corrected with query, but I have 3 companies with id 1 5 and 6, id 1 5 come out because I'm satisfied the 6 doesn't come out because the query is not satisfied I would also like the company with id 6

Comment: I changed `match` to `matches` because `match` is a reserved word. That should fix the error you got when you tried it.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'match FROM tev_Tipi_accreditamento AS s LEFT JOIN tev_Evidenze AS e ON s' at line 1

Comment: Did you read what I just wrote? I changed `match` to `matches` to fix that.

Comment: I've added a demo at db-fiddle.com, it shows id 6. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bmSpMhoiVsuzPGr8s3APWr/0

Comment: Because of your `WHERE` clause. It should be in the `ON` clause like my answer.